# How to add new lines inside of the object?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got this piece of code and I need to add inside of `this.info().Info` a new lines after each 10 words. I'm not very familiar with JavaScript and I'm learning it, but I don't know how to do this.
`this.info().Info` stores Lorem Ipsum text that is written inside of a field and than saved.

```
 $(this.data()).after('<tr class="info-row"><td colspan="100"><div>' + this.info().Info + '</div></td></tr>');
```

Comment: Why do you need to add a breakpoint after every 10th word? If it is to control the row length, you should instead rely on CSS to set a max character length, using `ch`. 50-60 characters per row has the best legability, but you can go as far as 75 if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mod (`%`) operator, which returns the remainder of `x / y`, for that. You can loop through each word to check if the index is divisible by 10 and if it is, add a `\n`.

Here is how to do that:

```js
function addNewlineEvery10Lines(text) {
  return text.split(" ").map((word, index) => { // get the words in an array and loop through them
    if ((index + 1) % 10 === 0) return word + "\n"; // add newline if divisible by 10
    return word; // just return word otherwise
  }).join(" "); // join the array back up
}
```

You can now use this function on the info.

```js
 $(this.data()).after('<tr class="info-row"><td colspan="100"><div>' + addNewlineEvery10Lines(this.info().Info) + '</div></td></tr>');
```